# Russian Characters in URL PHP

Tags: php, sql, urldecode

I have scoured the internet and I'm either not finding the answer or I'm unable to implement it correctly.

Basically I am trying to implement a website in Russian on PHP. I have already got the website in English and French but bringing a whole new range of characters in has sort of broken the test site. My actual goal is to have the Cyrillic characters in the URL, similar to how Wikipedia are able to do it > [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Компьютер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) and also still find this in the database to show the correct location information.

In my SQL database I have a range of locations, countries such as France, Germany, Australia etc. I have set it up so that the location page is generated dynamically from those entries using the $data['Name'] variable. Now... in the header.php file I use this to generate the location names from the database for the navigation:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Места</a>
    <ul>
        <?php if (is_array($locations)) {
            foreach ($locations as $key => $location) {
                $name = strtolower(str_ireplace(" ","-", $location['name']));
                if ($location['top_location'] == 1)
                    echo '<li><a href="'.$MASTER['base_url'].'location/'.$name.'">'.$location['name'].'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        ?>
     </ul>
</li>
```

Where $name is replaced by database entries. If I change one of the database entries to Russian (Australia for example - Австралия) then the location page throws a 404 error as it's actually trying to find `location/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F` rather than `location/Австралия`.

My location page has the following code to get information from the database:

```
<?php


    include './inc/utils.php';

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $name = str_ireplace("-"," ", $_GET['id']);
        $result = get_data("Locations", array("name" => $name))[0];
    }
    else
        $result = null;

    if ($result != null) {
        $data['Name'] = $result['name'];
        $data['Url_Name'] = $_GET['id'];
        $data['Image'] = $result['image'];
        $data['Slider_Text'] = $result['slider_text'];
        $data['Description'] = $result['description'];
        $data['Country'] = $result['top_location'] != 0 ? true : false;
        $data['Cars_In_Location'] = get_cars_in_location($result['id']);

        $img_url = $MASTER['car_img_url'];
        $link_url = $MASTER['base_url'].'car/';

        $cities_id = explode(",", $result['related']);

        foreach ($cities_id as $value) {
            $data['Related'][] = get_data("Locations", array("id" => $value))[0];
        }


    }
    else {
        $data['Name'] = "";
        $data['Url_Name'] = "";
        $data['Image'] = "";
        $data['Slider_Text'] = "";
        $data['Description'] = "";
        $data['Country'] = false;
        $data['Related'] = "";
        $data['Cars_In_Location'] = "";
    }

    if (empty($data['Name']) == true) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        header('Location: '.$MASTER['base_url'].'404.php');
  }

    include 'header.php';

?>
```

I have tried using [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to no avail. I think I am missing something either on the SQL side or in one of the function files.

my header.php file contains both 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and 
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

as well as my location page containing 
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
my .htaccess file has 
`AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

I don't know what else I'm missing.

You can see the page here:

[https://redfoxluxurycarhire.com/ru/location/Австралия](https://redfoxluxurycarhire.com/ru/location/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F)

I am using print_r($host_url) to correctly print the URL despite what it shows so you can see my issue. I am also able to echo Австралия onto the location pages with no problems or encoding.

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm wracking my brain as how to get this to work!

Comment: are you URL encoding the unicode characters or soomething?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.

Comment: I think that's got to be what's going on, just try echoing "Австралия" to the page, see if it works, if it does, then it's because SOMETHING is URL encoding the location links, and that automatically converts unicode to the percent escaped sequences, it won t really be a great fix since if you have a space in the location name it might get strange, but i want to say most browsers will escape unescaped URLS when clicked anyways

Comment: On the same page? Or any location page?

Comment: Just literally anywhere to confirm non-escaped text from PHP is output non-url encoded

Comment: I can confirm that I am able to echo "Австралия" on the location page with no issue - <h3><?php echo 'Австралия'; ?></h3> works just fine and output is exactly as it should be, no encoded output

Comment: Any other help would be welcome, this is still not working!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157666/discussion-between-zack6849-and-charles-syms).

Answer (score 1):

I would start checking if you have any file-systems encoding problem. Check your scripts are using UTF-8, I believe your MySQL database is OK. You should be able to decode requests with urldecode.

Comment: Hi there, my header.php file contains both <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> and header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); as well as my location page containing header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');..... my .htaccess file has 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 ...... I don't know what else I'm missing

Comment: open your script files from server with an editor like notepad++. You can use it to connect directly to the server via ftp/sftp and check encoding menu. I made this test http://193.231.40.249/test/ru.php Use IE and click the 2 links. They all decode correctly.

Comment: Hi Paun, I have tested in Edge as I don't have IE and the top link is going to http://193.231.40.249/test/ru.php?k=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F whereas the bottom link is going to http://193.231.40.249/test/ru.php?k=Австралия 

I don't fully understand what you mean by opening my server script files.

Comment: Sorry, do not know what's wrong with your code unless I have more info, or better access to your code. I did some websites with German, French, Romanian and Bulgarian chars and today technology has everything sorted out pretty OK.